# What is the purpose of t1.next=null below the while loop?

Tags: java, syntax, linked-list, logic

```
public class Solution {

    public static LinkedListNode<Integer> removeDuplicates(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
        //Your code goes here
        
        if(head==null){
            return head;
        }
        if(head.next==null){
            return head;
        }
        LinkedListNode<Integer> t1=head, t2=head.next;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> final_head=head;
        while(t2!=null){
             if(t1.data==t2.data){
                 t2=t2.next;
             }else{
                 t1.next=t2;
                 t1=t2;
             }
        }
                t1.next=null;
        return final_head;

    }
}
```

Why is it showing runtime error when I remove `t1.next=null` ?
Am I missing something here ? I dont undertand the purpose of `t1.next=null`.

Comment: Can you show the runtime error?

Comment: ... and the definition of class `LinkedListNode` as it is not a default Java class. And the code where `removeDuplicates` get's called, as I guess the exception is thrown there rather than in this method.

Answer (score 3):

Answering why `t1.next = null` is needed from a correctness point of view...

Consider a linked list like this

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> NULL
```

....Skipping a few initial iterations of the loop.... and when `t1` is and `t2` are pointing to the penultimate `3`.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> NULL
          ↑    
          t1
          t2
```

The `if` condition would be *true* and you would move `t2` to the last `3` (while `t1` still points to the penultimate `3`).

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> NULL
          ↑    ↑
          t1   t2
```

On the next iteration, the same `if` condition would be *true* and you would make `t2` *null* and break out of the `while` loop.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> NULL
          ↑          ↑
          t1         t2
```

Now, to get the effect of removing the duplicate 3s, you should make the *next* of `t1` as null.

From this,

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> NULL
          ↑   
          t1
```

Setting `t1.next = null` results in,

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
          ↑   
          t1
```

Comment: The question was why it throws an exception without `t1.next = null`. That is not answered by your answer, is it?

Comment: @AxelRichter The OP needs to provide more details to answer that. I've updated my answer stating this is answering why `t1.next = null` is needed from a correctness point of view.